# Is it possible to produce incorrect Metadata?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

There is an app on xposed installer called XPrivacy for android that let's you decide what information you want your device to give a specific app and for information you don't want to give it produces and sends fake information and allows the user to continue useing the app without giving up the any information the app doesn't *need* to function properly.

My question is: is their a way to make different applications create and send incorrect metadata so any kind of ad agency that builds a profile on what i search would get random\incorrect information from the user?

Comment: Of course there is. It will require you either pitting incorrect information into the app, or editing the app itself.